# How do I create an absolute file path from a QDir and a relative file path?

Tags: c++, qt

In my program I have a QDir representing the location of the executable using `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` and a `QString` that represents a path to a file relative to the executable directory (using .. , etc.). **How do I turn this information into an absolute file path to the same file?**

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`QFileInfo`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#QFileInfo-5) for that, use the constructor that takes a `QDir` and a `QString`, then call `absoluteFilePath` or `canonicalFilePath` depending on what you want exactly.

```
QDir dir;
// ...
QString file;
// ...
QFileInfo fi(dir, file);
QString canonical = fi.canonicalFilePath();
```

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest way is to use `QDir::absoluteFilePath`.

```
QDir dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
QString absolute_file_path = dir.absoluteFilePath(relative_file_path);
```